# Переадресация с формы обратной связи

Tags: php, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, на сайт поставил форму заявки, после успешного заполнения которой, открывается новая страница с текстом "Заявка успешно отправлена". Требуется, чтобы открывалась другая страница, назовем например "succes.html"

P.S. Только всему обучаюсь, извините если глупый вопрос, но ответа нужного не нашел, да и в знание PHP пока я полный ноль.

Вот код отправки формы:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$email = $_POST['email'];


$name = htmlspecialchars($name);
$tel = htmlspecialchars($tel);
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);


$name = urldecode($name);
$tel = urldecode($tel);
$email = urldecode($email);


$name = trim($name);
$tel = trim($tel);
$email = trim($email);


if (mail("mail@gmail.com",
        "Новая заявка",
        "Имя: ".$name."\n".
        "Телефон: ".$tel."\n".
        "Email: ".$email,
        "From: почта@маил.рф \r\n")

) {
    echo ('Письмо успешно отправлено!');
}

else {
    echo ('Есть ошибки! Проверьте данные...');
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Создайте нужную страницу и сделайте на нее переадресацию в нужный момент

```
<?php

/*...*/
if (mail("mail@gmail.com",
        "Новая заявка",
        "Имя: ".$name."\n".
        "Телефон: ".$tel."\n".
        "Email: ".$email,
        "From: почта@маил.рф \r\n")

) {
    header('Location: /success.html', true, 302);
    exit ('<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=/access.html" /></head><body><h1>Письмо успешно отправлено!</h1></body></html>');
}

else {
    echo ('Есть ошибки! Проверьте данные...');
}

/*...*/
```

Comment: Создал страницу, сделал переадресацию, и все равно ничего не происходит.

Comment: Проверил у себя, все отлично работает. А у вас точно письмо отправляется или же есть ошибки? Строку перенаправления что я указал выше, необходимо поставить прямо перед выводом сообщения 'Письмо успешно отправлено!'

Comment: Письмо отправляется, все работает нормально. Вставил точно так, как указали выше. Буду искать тогда в чем у меня ошибка. Спасибо.

Comment: У меня появилось подозрение, что что-то может перебить заголовок, поэтому я сделал в решении выше более надежно сменив echo() на exit(), чтобы точно ничто не могло изменить заголовок перенаправления. Попробуйте так

Comment: Все равно ноль эффекта. Форму обратной связи делал по шаблону и создавался файл - .htaccess, где стоит только кодировка UTF-8. Из-за этого файла может быть проблема?

Comment: Нет, эти изменения .htaccess незначительны, но все же для эксперимента можно удалить на время этот файл. Добавил meta redirect, он то уж точно сработает